# Scrolling Flutter Chips Horizontally

Tags: flutter

I have been playing around with flutter chips to make selectable tags to use for filtering:

[image]

I am trying to get the same effect but with a side scroll. But when I attempt this the chips are to evenly spaced between each other and it doesn't look as good as the vertical scroll.

[image]

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    spacing: 5,
                    runSpacing: 5,
                    children: listOfPackTags.map(
                      (category) {
                        return FilterChip(
                          selected: selectedTags.contains(category),
                          onSelected: (bool selected) {
                            if (selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedTags.add(category);
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedTags.remove(category);
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          label: Text(category),
                          showCheckmark: false,
                          selectedColor: const Color(0xFF93C3B9),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

It looks like the chips are aligning with the longest chip in their "column". I cant for the life of me figure out why spacing is based of the largest chip in each column. I have been playing with the alignment  and cross axis alignment properties but not getting anywhere productive.

Comment: Column definition says
"To cause a child to expand to fill the available vertical space, wrap the child in an Expanded widget.

The Column widget does not scroll (and in general it is considered an error to have more children in a Column than will fit in the available room). If you have a line of widgets and want them to be able to scroll if there is insufficient room, consider using a ListView.

For a horizontal variant, see Row."

Comment: Confused cause I have things in a row not a column here.

Comment: I just referred your text "it looks like the chips are aligning with the longest chip in their "column". I cant for the life of me figure out why spacing is based of the largest chip in each column. I have been playing with the alignment and cross axis alignment properties but not getting anywhere productive."

Comment: ooo gotcha. Yea that is why I put "column" in quotes. If you look at the code I pasted there is no column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your list into 3 rows (or whatever you want) and create a algorithm to re-order your list

```
int rows = 3;

SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: List.generate(
      rows,
      (index) {
        final offset = index * listOfPackTags.length ~/ rows;
        final end =
          listOfPackTags.length ~/ rows - 1 >= listOfPackTags.length
          ? listOfPackTags.length - 1
          : listOfPackTags.length ~/ rows - 1;
        return Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 5,
          runSpacing: 5,
          children: listOfPackTags.sublist(offset, offset + end).map(
            (category) {
              return FilterChip(
                selected: selectedTags.contains(category),
                onSelected: (bool selected) {
                  if (selected) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedTags.add(category);
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedTags.remove(category);
                    });
                  }
                },
                label: Text(category),
                showCheckmark: false,
                selectedColor: const Color(0xFF93C3B9),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

This make each rows have same **number of items**, not same **width** size. It will be better if you take control by width of `Chip` items. You can <s>caculate</s> approximate it by **length** of each `listOfPackTags` item, and **number of items** in each row (more rows is more paddings). But i think it isn't efficient.